# How to implement "archivable" collection?

Tags: scala, data-structures, collections

I'd like to implement a collection of elements in Scala with the following specification:

- Each item has a unique identifier (UUID)
- Collection consists of an "active" part (behaves like `Set[A]`) and an "archived" part (a `Set[UUID]`)
- Elements are "archived" based on a function `archivable: A => Boolean`
- "Archived" elements are removed from the "active" part with their identifiers placed into the "archived" part
- The archiving overhead should be constant or amortized (log is fine, but not linear)
- The collection cannot be instantiated to an invalid state, i.e. one where an element that should be archived is placed in active, however it can be in such an invalid state for a finite period of time (if it is necessary to trade correctness for overhead)
- As little code and boilerplate as possible

Here is a tentative implementation that works relatively well as long as an active element cannot be archived before it is updated.

```
class ItemsCollection[A](archivable: A => Boolean)(private val _active: Map[UUID, A], private val _archived: Set[UUID]) {
  private def this(items: Iterable[A] = Seq.empty[A]) = this(items filterNot archiveable map (t => (t.id -> t)) toMap, items filter archiveable map (_.id) toSet)

  def active = _active.values
  def archived = _archived

  def +(item: A): ItemsCollection =
    if(archivable(item)) {
      new ItemsCollection(_active - item.id, _archived + item.id)
    } else {
      new ItemsCollection(_active + (item.id -> item), _archived)
  }
}
```

Works with:

```
def archivedByPriority(item: A): Boolean = item.priority == Low
```

Wouldn't work with:

```
def archivedByTimestamp(item: A): Boolean = item.timestamp + 1.hour < DateTime.now()
```

I'm also very happy to take feedback on whether this is the right way to implement such a collection and whether there is a more idiomatic way of doing this in Scala.

Comment: just a remark, you can use `items partition` instead of calling filter two times

Comment: what are the possible size limits for your collection?

Comment: @Ashalynd: I know about partition, but can I use it inside this()? If so, how?

Comment: @Ashalynd: Ideally, there shouldn't be more than 1k active elements, but possibly up to 100k or 1M archived elements. Then again, I would prefer a solution that works with any size (as long as it fits in memory). Since my main goal with this collection is to avoid dealing with archived elements (unless absolutely necessary), you can safely assume that the archived set is at least two orders of magnitude larger than the active set.